# Ruby: How to check contents array before printing out as comma seperated in ERB

Tags: ruby, erb, chef-infra

In Chef I have an array that I would like to print out comma separated, but I would also like to make sure that each of the values exist in another array.  Is there a simple one line way of both printing out the array and also validating the contents.  In the past I'd done

The current printing only line:

```
hostgroups <%= n.run_list.roles.to_a.join(",") %>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd do it like this:

```
hostgroups <%= (n.run_list.roles.to_a & another_a).join(",") %>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using the `select` method for an array?

I'm assuming that `other_collection` as the "allowed" words here.

```
hostgroups <%= n.run_list.roles.to_a.select {|elem| other_collection.include? elem}.join(",") %>
```

Let me know if it helps!

**Edit**
Link to the documentation for Array in Ruby: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html